# Change order of factor levels in sjPlot interaction plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, interaction, sjplot

I have the following kind of interaction plot made with sjPlot, showing an interaction between two categorical variables. The levels seem to appear alphabetically in the plot - however, I would like them ordered low -> average -> high.

[image: interaction plot]

The code used to generate this plot is

```
plot_model(model, type = "pred", terms = c("education", "gender"))
```

Is there a way to specify/change the order in which levels of a factor are supposed to show up in the plot? Seems related to this question which unfortunately received no answers: [Reorder groups of factor for sjPlot::plot_model in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68039242/reorder-groups-of-factor-for-sjplotplot-model-in-r) and to this one as well, but I would have to access something else than the facets [Adjusting facet order and legend labels when using plot_model function of sjplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57080850/adjusting-facet-order-and-legend-labels-when-using-plot-model-function-of-sjplot/57084535#57084535)

Edit:
Another example with the starwars dataset from dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sjPlot)
model = lm(height ~ gender*species, data = starwars[starwars$species == "Human" | starwars$species == "Droid" | starwars$species == "Twi'lek",])

plot = plot_model(model, type = "pred", terms = c("species", "gender"))
```

This yields
[image: plot]

Say I would prefer to have the humans in the middle of the plot to be better able to see how they differ from droids and Twi'lek on each side.
scale_x_discrete(limits = c("low", "average", "high")) unfortunately only changes the labels of the x-axis, but I would like to move not only the labels but also the corresponding data points around on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While at a first glance the `x` scale looks like a discrete scale it is actually a continuous scale, in which case the `limits` trick I mentioned in my comment does not work.

One option to fix that would be to convert the `x`  axis variable to a `factor` with the order of the `levels` set in the desired order.

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(sjPlot)

dat <- starwars[starwars$species == "Human" | starwars$species == "Droid" | starwars$species == "Twi'lek", ]

dat$species <- factor(dat$species, levels = c("Droid", "Human", "Twi'lek"))

model = lm(height ~ gender*species, data = dat)

plot_model(model, type = "pred", terms = c("species", "gender"))
```

[image]